# JQuery datapicker convert between formats

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

My application works with dates in the format `'M dd, yy'`, but the table sorter plugin I'm using needs to be able to normalize the date for sorting to the format `'mm/dd/yy'`.

I've tried `$.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', 'Dec 4, 2014')`, but with no luck. I've also looked at the documentation and couldn't find anything. http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Here's an example.
Nov 06, 2014 to 11/06/2014.

Is there a way I can freely convert between date formats in JQuery datepicker? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myDate = new Date('Nov 06, 2014');
var newDate = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + myDate.getDate() + "/" + myDate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Thanks lol I actually found the same thing right as you answered. Here's how I did it. `var newDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', Date('Dec 04, 2014'));`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) library. It includes a ton of methods to format, manipulate, etc...

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely check it out if I run into any more problems. For now the other answer seems to work for me without needing to add a new library.